# Chai assertion for .to.have.property('method', <any function>);

Tags: mocha.js, chai

I wonder if there is a way to do this in Chai (including third-party options):

```
expect(obj).to.have.property('method', <any function>);
expect(obj).to.have.property('prop', <any object>);
```

While Jasmine doesn't provide exactly these matchers out of the box, it can be done with third-party [Jasmine matchers](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers).

I would prefer one-liner that can give valuable feedback on failure instead of

```
expect(obj).to.have.property('method');
expect(obj.method).to.be.a('function');
```

Comment: Same issue here... I want to call a function that returns the value I want to compare.

Comment: Just to be clear: you would like to give an object as second argument and match whether the given property value deeply matches that object?

Comment: @MarcoL I was thinking about something like `jasmine.any(Object)` counterpart in Chai that matches every object which is compared against it. So `obj.prop` could pass if it is an object and fail if it is not.

Comment: How that would be different from [`expect(obj).to.have.property('method').that.is.a('function')`](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_property)?

Comment: @MarcoL And this is something I didn't know, I expected that `that` is just a synonym to `and`. I would anticipate better output (it throws *expected [Function] to be an object* and doesn't specify property name).

Answer (score 1):

You can test it like this:

```
var obj = {
  aFunction: function () { }, aProperty: ''
};
expect(typeof obj.aFunction).to.be.equals('function');
expect(obj.aProperty).to.exist;
```